# IE8 HTTPs Download Issue

Tags: security, ssl, internet-explorer

I have a problem with a system I develop related to IE8 downloading over SSL (ie on sites using `https://`...) and is described on [this MS kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308).

We use the `HTTPCacheability.NoCache` option as the data being downloaded is sensitive, and is downloaded from a secured site. I don't want that data to be cached on any of the proxies, the client, or the server.

The article describing the issue details a fix to the client side registry changing a `BypassSSLNoCacheCheck` setting.

I don't want to loosen the system security just for IE8, as the system works fine on anything more upto date. Getting all the clients to apply the hotfix is difficult at best, and impossible at worst. We need to support IE8 in the system, at least for now.

So:

1. Does the detailed hotfix have any implications for the security at the browser end in IE8 - does it mean the file will be cached? (in a place other than where the user saves the file).
2. Is there some way I can get these files downloadable with a change at the server end that doesn't break the security side of things?

Answer (score 1):

Relying on a client browser cache setting does not add much security.  Have you tried ServerAndPrivate?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: ServerAndPrivate does remove the download error, but causes the doc to be cached, even if its only on the server or by the client. We're a little bit subject to Pen Testers for this, but the NoCache setting has been corroborated by a couple of different Pen Tests and other sources.